# Composer 0.14 - Error: The current identity has not been registered: admin

Tags: hyperledger-composer

After the update to 0.14, I am no more able to connect to the chain from the cli

```
composer network ping -p hlfv1 -n basic-sample-network -i admin -s adminpw
```

or

```
composer-rest-server -p hlfv1 -n basic-sample-network -i admin -s adminpw -N never
```

I have the following error

```
Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Error trying to query business network. 
Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Error: The current identity has not been registered: admin)
```

All composer component were updated to 0.14, and the test was made with basic-sample-network. For information, `npm test` on this exemple was perfectly.

OS: Ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please confirm that you have read the 0.14.0 release notes, particularly the "How to deal with this change" section:
https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/releases/tag/v0.14.0

You need to update your ACLs and redeploy your network, binding a network admin participant.

> There are two ways for specifying the business network administrators
>   on the command line: Note: This option is the one most users will
>   want! When running composer network deploy and composer network start,
>   in addition to the normal parameters you would use, you should also
>   include -A admin -S to bind the admin identity as a network admin
>   participant. If you don't do this, the identity you use to deploy the
>   business network, usually PeerAdmin, will be bound into the business
>   network as a business network administrator, and this is probably not
>   what you want.

Comment: I confirm that I have read the release note, and because I could not make it works with my how dev, I used basic-sample-network repo which was updated for 0.14.0 to make tests

Comment: Please include the command you used to `composer network deploy` and `composer network start`. Did you include the `-A admin -S` as described in the release note? What was the output from the command?

Comment: To deploy, I use:

    `composer network deploy -a dist/basic-sample-network.bna -p hlfv1 -i PeerAdmin -s randomString`

Comment: To start Fabric, I use Fabric-tools commands: 
`./downloadFabric.sh && ./startFabric.sh && ./createComposerProfile.sh`. Fabric-tools were updated too.

Comment: Understood!!! It would have been more comfortable in the release note, a sentence like: To correct the breaking changes, deploy your blockchain with the following command `composer network ping -p hlfv1 -n basic-sample-network -i admin -s adminpw`. Now it works fine, thanks for your help